# Where do code snippets reside in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets

The only C/C++ extension I have is the [official one](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools) from Microsoft. I do not have any other snippet/intellisense/autocompletion extension.

See below all the extensions loaded:

[image]

In trying to create shortcut keys/prefixes for my snippets, I would like to make sure that it does not clash with any pre-existing shortcuts/prefixes for other snippets. Is there a way to know / look through all currently available code snippets in VSCode and their shortcut keys/prefixes?

I tried to `Insert Snippet` via the command pallette in the hope that it would reveal all available snippets. Unfortunately, it does not list all snippets. See, for instance, below image, where this command pallette does not show the existence of a `for` snippet and yet inside the editor, when I type `for`, there is an option to add such a snippet.

[image]

Comment: you have snippets and code completions, a code completion can be a snippet

Comment: have you read the snippet doc page? some snippets live in extensions, workspace, global user snippets dir

Comment: Just figured out from https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets that `Ctrl space` gives an exhaustive list. I think I should just scroll through that to see if any keyword/shortcuts/prefixes are used already.

Comment: What is confusing, however, is the following: `You can see the available snippets for a language by running the Insert Snippet command in the Command Palette to get a list of the snippets for the language of the current file. However, keep in mind that this list also includes user snippets that you have defined, and any snippets provided by extensions you have installed` on that page. The image before this paragraph shows a for built in snippet, and yet that does NOT show up from the command pallette.

Comment: they don't update the images for each VSC update, only if you create an issue and it is a miss for a new feature

Comment: I understand, but as mentioned in the OP, the gif that I have with a recent version 1.60 of VSCode does not list the `for` snippet at all. If I understand you correctly, you are saying that `for` is a code completion and not a snippet and hence it does not appear in the command pallette snippet list?

Comment: it is very hard for the snippet collector to also know which snippets will be created by Completion providers, if you can 't find the `for` snippet in the snippet.json file that it most likely is a completion item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Snippets defined by extensions are stored in JSON files with the extension's contents. Open the extension's directory in the `.vscode/extensions/` directory in your user home directory, and then open its package.json file ([extension manifest](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/extension-manifest)), look for the `"snippets"` property, which will point to the paths of its snippet files.

Extensions can also provide snippets dynamically through the VS Code API. See also the [`SnippetString`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#SnippetString) interface. Snippets can be provided by an extension in multiple ways, including through [`CompletionItem`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#CompletionItem)s (suggestions), [`DocumentDropEdit`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#DocumentDropEdit)s, [`InlineCompletionItems`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#InlineCompletionItem), [`SnippetTextEdit`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#SnippetTextEdit)s, [`TextEdit`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#TextEdit)s, or [`TextEditor#insertSnippet`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#TextEditor). If you want to know about all those, this probably means reading source code for the extension. Some extensions even have a separation between frontend and backend, with closed-source backends (such as the Microsoft C++ extension).

To open user-level snippets, you can just open the snippet file in VS Code (use `Snippets: Configure User Snippets` in the command palette), and the full path can be obtained by hovering the tab handle, or in the breadcrumbs, or by using `File: Copy Path of Active File`.

Profiles can also have snippet files. You can find them in the `snippets/` directory of the profile's storage (under `.../Code/User/profiles`, where `...` is some [platform specific path](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settings-file-locations))

You can also have [workspace/project snippets](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_project-snippet-scope) (snippets that only apply for a specific workspace) in the `.vscode/` directory of the workspace folder with filenames ending in `.code-snippets`.

Answer (score 0):

I obtained confirmation officially from `vscode-cpptools` folks that `C/C++` snippets are only available via `Ctrl-Space` autocomplete and not via `Ctrl-Shift-P` Command Pallette.

See link to their answer [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/discussions/8193#discussioncomment-1405997).

Answer (score -1):

Take a look in these folders

***C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\[20XX]\[VS_Edition]\Common7\IDE***

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\[20XX]\[VS_Edition]\Common7\IDE\Extensions

C:\Users[Name]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\XX.xx......\[LCID]

and files...

***HTML Example***

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\[20XX]\[VS_Edition]\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\Languages\Schemas\HTML\***html.xsd***

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\[20XX]\[VS_Edition]\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\Languages\Schemas\HTML\***CommonHTMLTypes.xsd***

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\20XX[VS_Edition]\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\Languages\Schemas\HTML\***xml.xsd***

Snippets and extensions can be found in ***Tools*** -> ***Code Snippets Manager*** (Ctrl+K,Ctrl+B)

In the window set a program lang then select any folder in the list below. The corresponding snippet/extension path will be visible in the label Location: in this case the snippet about for loop in C++ can be found  in this path c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\20XX\[vs_editon]\common7\ide\vc\snippets\[lcid]\visual c++\for.snippet; It's preferable to make a copy of all files before changing them so you don't have to repair or reinstall Visual Studio in case something doesn't work correctly. And I tried to include some images but I got an error message from StackOverflow requiring me at least 10 of reputation score to post images, in fact this is so depress. I nevermore will desire to be abble to refact an IDE's code and not be abble to publish screenshots by only one reputation's point that and I never knew for what this works. But now I understand better my ex wife when she told me that I'm good for nothing.

Comment: VSCode (what this question is about) is different from Visual Studio IDE (what you have answered)